# My subject column contains lot of different keyword, how do I write SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data based on subject and Class.column name for classes is (Class_I_V Class_VI_VIII Class_IX_X Class_XI_XII).

MY query is like this:

```
subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%'
or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%'
or subject LIKE '%$search%' or Class_I_V LIKE '%$search%' ".
```

I have lot of values in subject column. Shall I want to give all subject combination like this `(subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%')`?

Because my subject column contains lot of keyword. kinldy see the db my table is tutor and column is subject.can any give me a perfect query for this

Myurl: http://tutorquery.comuv.com/search.php give physics or java or Class I -V

```
search.php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$search=$_POST['search'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT name,subject,place,expyrs,Class_I_V FROM tutor WHERE subject LIKE '%$search%' or  subject LIKE '%$search%'  or  subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%' Or Class_I_V LIKE '%Class I -V%' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo ++$sno; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['expyrs'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Class_I_V'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I've reformatted your question a bit to show how we like questions to appear here. In particular, the code formatting device is not appropriate for paragraph text. Also, it is good that you showed your database structure, but a private phpMyAdmin instance with a username and password is not the way to do it. We want questions to be useful forever, but it is reasonable to expect that those credentials will stop working soon, and so anyone wanting to understand the database structure in the future cannot do so. Please edit database structure information *into* the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the $search variable will always be a single search string, each LIKE statement is going to be identical. Your query can be shortened up to...

```
SELECT 
name, subject, place, expyrs, Class_I_V
FROM
tutor
WHERE
subject LIKE '%$search%'
    Or Class_I_V LIKE '%Class I -V%';
```

Comment: IF I want to write query for column  Class_I_V  or Class_VI_VIII  Class_IX_X or Class_XI_XII. shall i write like this ? Class_I_V LIKE '%Class I -V%' or  Class_VI_VIII LIKE '%Class_VI_VIII%' like this

Comment: Exactly! For each unique search term you will need to have separate variables. Otherwise ambiguity is created. are there separate columns for each one of those?

Comment: ok.now the search term consist only one variable . when do I want to give the query like this  SELECT subject   FROM  tutor WHERE subject LIKE '%physics%' OR subject LIKE '%Maths%' OR subject LIKE '%Hindi%  Or Class_I_V LIKE '%Class I -V%';

Comment: The database does not know the difference between the subjects. It can only look for data that is within the search string. The query you provided will search for any string, withing the subject column, that is anywhere within the field.

Comment: Ok Thanks for reply. You have answered query